# Google Map JavaScript error after migrating

Tags: javascript, google-maps

After migrating `www.irfc.eu` from previous domain, Google Map (it's a widget of the theme) stopped working. JavaScript console says:

Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error_.ib@js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&ver=1:34`

I think problem is in the site source code. `&#038;` should be just `&`. But I can't find a place where to change it.

[image]

Maybe it's something else regarding JavaScript.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question is not about WordPress but about the Google Maps API

Answer (score 1):

Google API's now requires API key for new domains,

you should create an API key as per instructions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

and edit the line in the plugin that loads the Google Maps API to include your key as the value of a 'key' parameter.

Wherever you find one of these:

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"

or

"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" in the `functions.php` file,

and change it to "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY".

Notice that you should replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with the key you created at first.